# component unmounts before transition ends

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have a react component, a sidebar menu that goes in and out of the screen with a transform:translateX and has a transition of 1s. The problem is that the component unmounts before the transition ends, which makes the menu component to be entirely white and empty and it doesn't look good. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: add your relevant code please

Comment: Yes, please add at least a code snippet to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an event that is called onTransitionEnd, and use it to toggle (hide or show) the sidebar menu.

For more info see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event